# Create single exe from Python 3.6 scripts in CX_Freeze

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze

I have a Python script which i would like to compile into a single executable file, I have read that PyInstaller is the best option for this but unfortunately CX_Freeze is the only compiler I have found to work with Python 3.6.

Is there a way to do this with CX_Freeze?

Answer (score 4):

First you must have cx_freeze 5.0.1 as it supports python 3.6 .

Then,it's like any 3.X version .
Put this code in setup.py file and replace :

```
"prog.py"
```

with your main script name.

Take care and don't forgit if you will go Console it should be

```
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "console"
```

Here is the code :

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os"], "excludes": ["tkinter"]}

# GUI applications require a different base on Windows (the default is for a
# console application).
base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"


setup(  name = "my prog",
    version = "1.0",
    description = "My application!",
    options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    executables = [Executable("prog.py", base = base)])
```

Open command prompot write :

```
cd your directory path 
python setup.py build
```

Comment: I followed this steps, but I am getting the below error, when running my exe through cmd

`ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']`

but when I am importing numpy in my idle, it works fine


`>>> import numpy`
`>>>`

Comment: You just need to add numpy in the build_exe_options, some libraries need to be explicitly added there

Answer (score 0):

cx_freeze will generate an executable and all dependent files within your target folder. To package this into a 'single' executable I have used the free [Cameyo Packaging](http://www.cameyo.com) utility to virtualise the application. To get a more professional finish I also use the [Nullsoft Scriptable Install System (NSIS)](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Main_Page) system.

The sample code below takes the content of the build directory for a Python 3.7 application I developed call Timer. Just replace the source directories and program name with your equivalents.

```
;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Purpose:      Script to package a Python cx_freeze application into a single
;               executable covering initial install, upgrades, and execution
; Author:       Ed Sheehan
; Revision:     2018-12-14 Initial development
;------------------------------------------------------------------------------

!include "MUI2.nsh" ;Required for splash screen

CRCCheck on ;Prevent execution if package corrupted or manipulated by third party
RequestExecutionLevel user ;Invoke as user to prevent request for elevated rights
SilentInstall silent ;Suppress standard progress windows of installer 

Name "Meeting Master"
OutFile Timer.exe

;Set the package icon and property details
!define MUI_ABORTWARNING
!define MUI_ICON "D:\Build\favicon.ico"
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"
VIProductVersion "2018.12.14.01"
VIAddVersionKey /LANG=${LANG_ENGLISH} "ProductName" "Timer"
VIAddVersionKey /LANG=${LANG_ENGLISH} "FileVersion" "2018.12.14.01"
VIAddVersionKey /LANG=${LANG_ENGLISH} "FileDescription" "Meeting agenda timer"
VIAddVersionKey /LANG=${LANG_ENGLISH} "ProductVersion" "0.001.a"
VIAddVersionKey /LANG=${LANG_ENGLISH} "LegalCopyright" "Copyright (c)2018 Navem Pty Ltd"

;Write application to users roaming location and save splash screen in temporary area
Function .onInit
    SetOutPath $APPDATA\Timer
    InitPluginsDir
    File "/oname=$PluginsDir\splash.jpg" "D:\Build\splash.jpg"
FunctionEnd

;Extract / upgrade / run the application
Section "Installer Section"
    newadvsplash::show /NOUNLOAD 5000 500 500 -2 /BANNER "$PLUGINSDIR\splash.jpg" ;Long running splash screen if first time install or replacement (upgrade)
    IfFileExists $APPDATA\Timer\Ver_2018_12_14_001 Launcher 0 ;Run immediately if installed version file matches
    IfFileExists $APPDATA\Timer 0 NewInst ;Remove if different version installed and then install this version and run

    ;Remove old version (remember RMDIR will not work on active OurPath)
    SetOutPath $APPDATA
    RMDir /r $APPDATA\Timer
    SetOutPath $APPDATA\Timer

NewInst:
    ;Install this version
    File /r D:\Build\*.*
    Goto Skip

Launcher:
    ;Short pause to ensure splash screen is visible
    Sleep 500

Skip:
    ;Launch the application and ensure splash screen is cleared
    Exec $APPDATA\Timer\Timer.exe
    Sleep 1000
    newadvsplash::stop /FADEOUT

SectionEnd
```